# Universal property of categorical quotients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

I'm approaching the arguments in Mumford's book Geometric Invariant Theory and i have a question which i hope is not too naive..

I've read that, given a group scheme $G/S$ acting on $X/S$, we say that $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a categorical quotient if:

1) $\pi$ is invariant with respect to the action of $G/S$

2) $\pi$ is "universal", i.e. for every $\tau:X\rightarrow Z$ invariant with respect to the action of $G/S$, there exists a unique $\psi:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $\tau=\psi\pi$

Now i have trouble understanding the definition of Orbit space quotient (i.e. categorical quotient in which geometric fibers are exactly the orbits of the geometric points of $X$).

In particular my question is: if a Orbit space quotient exists then shouldn't it be that every categorical quotient is an orbit space quotient (due to the universal property)? Because if i take $\tau:X\rightarrow Z$ an orbit space quotient then two geometric points $Spec(\overline{k(z_1)})\rightarrow Z$, $Spec(\overline{k(z_2)})\rightarrow Z$ have two geometric fibers $X_{\overline{z_1}}$, $X_{\overline{z_2}}$ which are exactly the orbits $G_{x_1}$ and $G_{x_2}$ of two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ of $X$. But then, if $G_{x_1}$ and $G_{x_2}$ are sent via $\pi$ to the same point $y\in Y$ (i.e. orbits of $\pi$ are not exactly the orbits) then $\tau$ can not factor through $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. What is the difficulty?

Comment: just wanted to be sure i'm understanding correctly

Comment: If an orbit space quotient is a categorical quotient by definition, then the answer is trivially yes, by uniqueness of the categorical quotient.

Comment: @edgar: The notion of categorical quotient arises because a strict "orbit space quotient" (which one really wants) doesn't always exist, in which case the categorical notion is a weaker substitute.  Like other commenters I don't see any difficulty here.